# Fill JPanel with BufferedImage and print it on printer

Tags: java, swing, printing, bufferedimage

I want to fill a panel with a BufferedImage (striped, see link below) and print it on a printer. The thing is that the pattern doesn't print, but it is visible as wanted on the panel. If I use a color instead of the striped image this gets printed.

You see two comments in the paintComponent-method below. Any ideas why I don't see the BufferedImage when I print?

Thanks!

You can find the image used here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMerO.jpg

```
package printbufferedimagepanel;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.TexturePaint;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import static java.awt.print.Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
import static java.awt.print.Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class PrintBufferedImagePanel {   
    JFrame mainFrame;
    JPanel mainPanel;
    Buff printMe;
    JButton printButton;
    BufferedImage bf;

    public PrintBufferedImagePanel() {
        prepareGUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintBufferedImagePanel bip = new PrintBufferedImagePanel();
    }

    private void prepareGUI() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame();
        mainFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        printMe = new Buff();
        printButton = new JButton("Print");
        mainPanel.setSize(400, 150);
        mainPanel.add(printMe);
        mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
        mainFrame.add(printButton);
        mainFrame.setSize(400, 250);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

        printButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
                job.setPrintable(printMe);
                boolean ok = job.printDialog();
                if (ok) {
                    try {
                        job.print();
                    } catch (PrinterException de) {
                        System.err.println("Oops!");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    class Buff extends JPanel implements Printable {
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400,150);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g); 

            BufferedImage bImage = null;
            TexturePaint tp = null;
            try {
                bImage = ImageIO.read(new File("src/printbufferedimagepanel/blueStripes.jpg"));
                tp = new TexturePaint(bImage, new Rectangle(0,0,bImage.getWidth(),bImage.getHeight()));
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
                g2.setPaint(tp); //<-- doesn't show at print, Why?              
                //g2.setColor(Color.CYAN); //<-- does show at print
                g2.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 150);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("oops");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
            if (pageIndex > 0) {
                return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            }

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)graphics;
            g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());

            this.printAll(graphics);
            return PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your passing the wrong graphics context to printAll `this.printAll(graphics);` to start with, not sure if that will have an effect though

Comment: Don't load the resource is the paint method and don't reference `src` in any way, use `Class#getResource` instead

Comment: printAll has the wrong graphics, yes, no effect though when I change. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: What OS and Java version?  Verified on MacOS (Yosemite) and Java 8.  There does seem to be a bug report with openJDK for a simular problem

Comment: I run Yosemite 10.10.3 and Java 8. Ok, where can I read the bug report?

Comment: [BugReport](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8040635)

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer, seems like the same issue...